# How do I switch database using a PreparedStatement (worried about sql injection)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple jdbc application that talks to a sql server.

Can I use the "use databaseName" in a PreparedStatement.

```
void useDatabase(Statement statement, String databaseName) throws SQLException {

    //This works but I was worried about sql injection as 
    //databaseName is provided by the user.
    //statement.executeUpdate("use \"" + databaseName + "\"");


    //So I tried this but I am 
    //Getting com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = statement.getConnection().prepareStatement("use ?");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, databaseName);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Use keyword docs: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx

Comment: You cannot parameterize [`USE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx). Note that it wants a *name*, not a *string*.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. How do I make it safe from sql injection?

Comment: Use `Connection.setCatalog()` instead